# Error in Main.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I am getting the error: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package:

I cannot find out why I am getting this error but I have been at it for hours without any sort of break through. I have searched google with many different resolutions but none that appear to work for me.

I would be grateful if someone could help direct me towards a fix to the error.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="org.nibbler.zoe.liteplayer.MainActivity" >

<item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Are you using the action bar compatibility library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `showAsAction` is not your attribute, hence not available in `app:` namespace. Did you mean `android:showAsAction`?

Comment: u are probably not right .if we add support res lib and ../res-auto , then we can have any namespace.

Comment: no. `res-auto` means your package id, not "any". and if you do not have it among your attributes, you will get that error.

Comment: then i think developer link for action bar is quite confusing , http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html .

Comment: can u please give light on this to know more on this-`Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the <menu> tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.`

Answer (score 0):

If u are having min ver below 14 and u want to add showAsAction for below 14 api devices, then u can use this.

`1.)U need support library to be added in build path.`

`2.)Need to add app theme as Theme.appcompat.`

`3)Rest are as u are using means add ur own namespace with .../res-auto value and use that name with showAsAction`

You can add support lib res like this http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

You need to extends ActionBarActivity instead of Activity.

For complete Action bar guide follow the link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html